# Can we have questions which ask for proofreading?

Tags: discussion

Like there is codereview.see,  can we have proofreading  questions on this site?

Comment: There are other sites specifically for proofreading,  like Lang-8. Proofreading doesn't really fit the question and answer format of Stack Exchange sites, because not too many folks benefit from a particular proofreading question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at this point in time, proofreading questions are not *generally* OK here.

One of the "off-topic" reasons on this site is "Proofreading"

> Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified. See: Alternative websites for proofreading

Meaning you can't just paste a block of text and ask us to "fix" it for you.

If you have a specific question about your text that you'd like to address, that's different.

I think the reason this could fall under off topic is that it's "primarily opinion based" or "every answer is right".

How to say something correctly is, to some degree, a matter of choice. English is complicated but that doesn't mean there aren't myriad ways to say the same thing.

You could have two or three completely acceptable answers where none of them are actually the same.

Comment: This only partly addresses the "why not" of this matter. There's another pragmatic reason, too: as soon as we start allowing proofreading questions, we open the floodgates. Anyone getting ready to submit a résumé, turn in a homework assignment, publish a blog post, write a proposal, or compose a love letter or apology can come by here first, post the text, and make a "simple" request: _Can you suggest any improvements?_ Even though we have plenty of folks here who like to be helpful, I don't think we want ELL to become inundated with free proofreading requests.

Comment: I wish there were a proofreading site on SE. I love correcting grammar!

Comment: @DogLover You're always welcome to recommend one on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). Though it seems that a proofreading site could lead to a lot of opinion-based questions.

Comment: @Catija I have followed your advice and created a (likely controversial) [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90644/proofreading).

Answer (score -1):

I, personally, would have no problem with a question to proofread, as long as the text isn't too lengthy. Others, however, might object under any circumstances. 'Would someone proofread this text example for me?' would be a nonproductive question. 'What would be the correct tense for the verbs in this text?' is a better question because it addresses a specific topic.

Comment: This link addresses your question with some good answers & comments: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/258/should-proofreading-questions-be-closed-as-offtopic?rq=1

Comment: Is a specific question about the grammar in an example really proofreading though? Maybe my definition of proofreading is a lot narrower than others', but to me there's a big difference between "I'm not sure I'm using the correct tense in this sentence" and "Please correct any mistakes in this sentence for me." Proofreading to me means that you think everything is correct and you'd like someone to verify it, so there's no real question or topic. Potentially the answer is simply "yes it looks fine" which isn't particularly useful to anyone else.

Comment: @Colleen - RE: _Proofreading to me means that you think everything is correct and you'd like someone to verify it..._ Yes, I agree, but it can also mean two other things: (1) the author is pretty sure it's **not** correct, but has no clue about where the errors might be, or (2) the author is thinking that it's probably grammatically correct, but could stand some polishing and improvement. I think all three of those situations call for prompt closure of the question, lest we become a free proofreading service.